# Cannot unicode chinese character using python2

Tags: python

I try to initialize Chinese words in python3, but it throws `'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 98-100: character maps to <undefined>`

I already tried to place u before the words:

```
import re

CONTRACT_PARTY_KEYWORD = [u'lesser', u'lesse', u'出租方', u'承租方']
ADDRESS_KEYWORD = [u'城市', u'广州市房屋租赁合同']
DATE_KEYWORD = [u'因为', u'日期', u'月', u'自', u'日']
```

The console shows that `'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 98-100: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: The title says Python 2. The text says Python 3. Which one are you using?

Comment: Also, how is your source file encoded? UTF-8?

Comment: Is the script's file using utf-8? Maybe add a `# coding: utf-8` header. Also, you can `from __future__ import unicode_literals` so you don't need to put `u''` in front of all the strings.

Comment: After posting a question, it’s a good idea to watch the question for ten minutes or so, in case people have questions.

Comment: the source is written in python 2

Comment: Yes. I use utf-8

Comment: i already add `# coding: utf-8`

Comment: Use `pyupgrade` or `2to3-3.7` to upgrade your code to python3.7

Answer (score 0):

Add `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top of your file.